# Ionic and Crosswalk Can’t Generate Signed APK

Tags: ionic-framework, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I am trying to add crosswalk to my ionic. My apps are launched and working fine. However after I added Crosswalk, I can't generate signed apks anymore. I tried to remove crosswalk and it works again. How did you guys manage to get it working?

Here's what I did:

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
cordova platform add android
ionic build android

it builds fine except:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 34.909 secs
Built the following apk(s):
<--- this part is empty, usually it'll show the path of the apk generated

In Android Studio I get this error for the gradle sync.
NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.

When I try to generate signed apk, I get this error:
Missing Gradle Project Information. Please check if the IDE successfully synchronized its state with the Gradle Project Model.

I tried cordova platform add android@4.1, instead of using latest one. And I was able to build it with sdk 22.

However when I try to publish, I'm getting this problem.

```
It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change from version 103098 (target SDK 23) to version 104004 (target SDK 22).
```

Comment: What's version from your android studio?

Comment: I guess crosswalk plugin just optional feature for old devices and will eat more resources for your ionic app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps I followed to get signed apk is as-

open terminal and go to android file

```
$ cd projectDir/platforms/android
```

## and run this command to generate digital signature

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore exampleapp.keystore -alias example -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

# This will create a file in you **"projectDir/platforms/android"** directory with a name of exampleapp.keystore which will have digital signature.

# Now Create a file with name of release-signing.properties here in

**projectDir/platforms/android directory.**

# Provide details to this file about your signature.

```
*# signed apk details
storeFile=exampleapp.keystore
keyAlias=mindfull
storePassword=password
keyPassword=password*
```

Go to terminal and exit to main project directory by typing

```
 $ cd ../..
```

Run this command to build signed apk.

```
$ cordova build android --release
```

this will run many task and show something like this-

[image]

Now you can upload this apk on play store and share with your friend.

Have a nice day !!!
For more you can see here
https://randvblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/04/generate-signed-apk-for-android-using-gradle-for-cordova-6-0-0-in-ionic/